# Flow React: Cannot create element because React.Component [1] is not a React component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I just started to make use of flow a few weeks ago and from a week ago i've been getting a flow error on which i've no idea how to fix.

The code goes like this:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CookieStorage from "./../services/CookieStorage";
import type { Component as ComponentType } from "react";

type Props = {
    component: ComponentType<any, any>
}

class ProtectedRoute extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        const isAuthenticated     = this.isAuthenticated();
        const {...props}          = this.props;
        const AuthorizedComponent = this.props.component;

        return (
            <Route
                {...props}
                render={props => (
                    isAuthenticated ?
                        <AuthorizedComponent {...props} /> :
                        <Redirect to="/"/>
                )}
            />
        );
    }

    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        const data = CookieStorage.get("foobar");

        return data !== null;
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

In here flow throws this error:

```
Error:(23, 8) Cannot create `AuthorizedComponent` element because `React.Component` [1] is not a React component.
```

I don't know if i am doing a wrong import type or a wrong type declaration for the component that is to be rendered when the authentication example is ok.

I've copied this code from a website i don't remember where, but he was making use of this snippet using `const {component: Component} = this.props` and render it as `<Component {...props} />` which for me it seems a little ambiguous, which is why i changed the declaration a bit to make it easy to understand when reading, but still even doing the exact same code like the snipped where i copied this code, flow still throws that error.

I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/oscarr-reyes/b965d5c13a095866931b50a4334b8711) of this in case someone would knows a solution for this and would like to make a change, if no one is able to help me fix this in here, then i will send a ticket issue to their project using this gist

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use `React.ComponentType` instead?

```
import type { ComponentType } from "react";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CookieStorage from "./../services/CookieStorage";

type Props = {
  component: ComponentType<any>
}

class ProtectedRoute extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated();
    const { component: AuthorizedComponent, ...props } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route
        {...props}
        render={props => (
        isAuthenticated ?
          <AuthorizedComponent {...props} /> :
          <Redirect to="/"/>
        )}
      />
    );
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const data = CookieStorage.get("foobar");
    return data !== null;
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

See https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype

Comment: oh... i didn't know there was a declaration called `ComponentType`, i tried your method and it works.. do you mind to explain why it has to be that way?, i'll mark your answer as the solution after your update with the explanation

Comment: Because your prop is not a rendered component, but a type of component. I updated my answer, see https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype

Comment: You need a `type` before the `ComponentType`, otherwise linters will complain that `ComponentType` is unused. `import React, { Component, type ComponentType } from "react";`